# Is it possible to perform a select into table of object type?

Tags: oracle, plsql

So i have a type

```
create or replace type body T_Some_type is object
  (...fields)
```

and i have a table type made of rows of type T_Some_type

```
create or replace TYPE T_Some_Table IS TABLE OF T_Some_type;
```

and i would like to select rows from some view to this T_Some_Table

```
select * 
        into T_Some_Table
        from V_Some_View
```

Is this even possible, and are there any cons for doing it this way (if possible at all). 
Do columns in `T_Some_Type` have to be in same order as in `V_Some_View` or will plsql do binding here if names of columns are the same?

If not possible, what would be alternative?

Edit : Having bodies defined is assumed, they are not here as they are not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it is. You need to wrap your columns in the object's constructor and use the `BULK COLLECT` option in the `SELECT` statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_some_type AS OBJECT(f varchar2(10))
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_some_table IS TABLE OF t_some_type
/

DECLARE
   v_some_table t_some_table;
BEGIN
   SELECT t_some_type (dummy)
   BULK   COLLECT INTO v_some_table
   FROM   DUAL;
END;
```

As an aside, you also need to make sure that you create the object specification, not just the body (as in your example).

Columns in the `SELECT` must be in the same order as they're found in the object's constructor. If you have not explicitly defined a constructor, one explicitly exists with each column in the order declared in the specification.

The only downside to using this functionality is that a large number of rows will result in heavy memory usage. If you expect to use this to process a large number of rows, you should use a loop with the `LIMIT` clause.

---

It is possible to specify an explicit constructor, in addition to the column list found in the specification. The constructor can have whatever input you define, so, obviously, when you use an explicit constructor, you have to follow it's argument list. Here's an example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_some_type AS OBJECT
(
   f1 VARCHAR2 (10),
   CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION t_some_type (p_length NUMBER, p_value VARCHAR2)
      RETURN SELF AS RESULT
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY t_some_type AS
   CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION t_some_type (p_length NUMBER, p_value VARCHAR2)
      RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS
   BEGIN
      self.f1 := LPAD (p_value, p_length, p_value);
      RETURN;
   END t_some_type;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_some_table IS TABLE OF t_some_type
/

DECLARE
   v_some_table t_some_table;
BEGIN
   --Explicit Constructor
   SELECT t_some_type (10, dummy)
   BULK   COLLECT INTO v_some_table
   FROM   DUAL;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (v_some_table (1).f1);

   --Implicit Constructor
   SELECT t_some_type (dummy)
   BULK   COLLECT INTO v_some_table
   FROM   DUAL;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (v_some_table (1).f1);
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers, i'm positively surprised this is possible. However i am not sure about example you provided, as it doesn't do what i wanted. I wanted to select rows from a view and into a table made of object type.
Also im not really sure what you mean by "Columns in the SELECT must be in the same order as they're found in the object's constructor".
As columns are defined in specification, not in construcor, otherwise they wouldn't be accesible from outside of the objects scope, or am i wrong?

Comment: I've changed the literal in my initial example to use the `dummy` column from `dual`. Typically, anywhere you can use a literal in DML, you can also use a column name.

Comment: I've been messing with it, until i finally got it, i didn't realize that  for object types, in select i need to use the type and params go within parentheses, which wasnt the case for record types. Thanks for you time and effort. Knowing this opens up a bunch of possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, more or less how the OP wanted to do it:

```
SELECT *
  BULK COLLECT INTO v_some_table
  FROM <some_source_table>;
```

For more detail, see: https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/on-bulk-collect - worked for me in Oracle 12.1.

Answer (score 1):

you can set fields from select by example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_some_type AS OBJECT(f varchar2(10), y varchar2(10))
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_some_table IS TABLE OF t_some_type
/

DECLARE
   v_some_table t_some_table;
   v_counter int;
BEGIN
   SELECT t_some_type (column_1, column_2)
   BULK   COLLECT INTO v_some_table
   FROM   some_table;

   -- show the count data fetched

   dbms_output.put_line( 'counter value: ' || to_char(v_counter));

END;
```