# PL/SQL error "not enough values" during "select into"

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm working on creating a pl/sql function that finds the highest average of students from a list of classes. I have the average computation part working correctly; however, I need to return the results as a table of records and I'm running into the error while attempting to store the results into the record.

My record declaration is as follows

```
create or replace TYPE studentRec as object (
    term     varchar2(10),
    lineNum  number(4),
    coTitle  varchar2(50),
    stuId    varchar2(5),
    average  number);
```

The error comes when I'm trying to fill the record using a `select into` statement.

```
create or replace function highest_avg(stu_id   scores.sid%type,
                                       line_no  scores.lineno%type)
return stuRecTab
as
    stuRec stuRecTab;
    average number;
    studentRec_t studentRec;
begin
    stuRec := stuRecTab();

    select avg(points)
      into average
      from scores, courses
     where scores.sid = stu_id
       and scores.lineno = line_no
       and scores.term = courses.term
       and scores.lineno = courses.lineno;

    SELECT DISTINCT c.term, c.lineno, cc.ctitle, s.sid, average
      INTO studentRec_t
      from courses c, class_catalog cc, scores s
     where s.sid = stu_id
       and s.lineno = line_no
       and s.term = c.term
       and s.lineno = c.lineno
       and c.cno = cc.cno;

    stuRec := studentRec_t;
    return(stuRec);
end;
```

I've run it as just a query and I'm getting back what I expect so I'm not sure why this error is popping up. Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is my first time working with pl/sql.

Comment: [Is it possible to perform a select into table of object type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30305161/is-it-possible-to-perform-a-select-into-table-of-object-type)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to perform a select into table of object type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30305161/is-it-possible-to-perform-a-select-into-table-of-object-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can't `SELECT INTO` the fields of an object instance variable - you have to create an object instance in your select, then SELECT that INTO your object instance variable. You can't simply assign an instance variable to a collection - you need to put it at an appropriate index. So what you end up with is something like:

```
create or replace function highest_avg(stu_id   scores.sid%type,
                                       line_no  scores.lineno%type)
return stuRecTab
as
    stuRec stuRecTab;
    average number;
    studentRec_t studentRec;
begin
    stuRec := stuRecTab();

    select avg(points)
      into average
      from scores s
      inner join courses c
        on c.term = s.term and
           c.lineno = s.lineno
     where s.sid = stu_id and
           s.lineno = line_no;

    SELECT studentRec(term, lineno, ctitle, sid, average)
      INTO studentRec_t
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT c.term, c.lineno, cc.ctitle, s.sid, average
              from scores s
              INNER JOIN courses c
                ON s.term = c.term and
                   s.lineno = c.lineno
              INNER JOIN class_catalog cc
                ON cc.cno = c.cno
              where s.sid = stu_id and
                    s.lineno = line_no);

    stuRec(1) := studentRec_t;
    return(stuRec);
end;
```

As no test data was provided I haven't tested this - but at least [it compiles at dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a3b1b18f399067c20db836789ab8117c).

Comment: I suggest you embellish your answer and replace the old, Oracle [SQL] syntax for joining tables in a query with the standard `JOIN`.